# Need second CIDR block for AWS VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ip-address, subnet, cidr

I have a CIDR block of 172.25.0.0/16 and need to create a second one for a new vpc I need to create.
I do not want the CIDR to overlap. Can someone help in identifying which I can use?

- Then for that I also need 2 private subnets.. then 2 public subnets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AWS recommends](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Subnets.html) using CIDRs from the following ranges:

> 10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255 (10/8 prefix)   Your VPC must be /16 or smaller, for example, 10.0.0.0/16.

> 172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255 (172.16/12 prefix)    Your VPC must be /16 or smaller, for example, 172.31.0.0/16.

> 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255 (192.168/16 prefix)     Your VPC can be smaller, for example 192.168.0.0/20.

Since you area already using `172.25.0.0/16` you can choose `172.30.0.0/16`, `10.0.0.0/16` or whatever you want from these ranges.

Comment: thank you was very helpful. I will be using 172.30.0.0/16. Also, what about the 2 private and 2 public subnets I need to create?

Comment: @Myra No problem. You can use `172.30.1.0/24` and `172.30.2.0/24` if you want.